# I am getting the following error while a was scaffolding my database?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

```
Scaffold-DbContext "'server=MyPc\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Test;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;'" 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' -Verbose
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Setting app base path C:\DotNetCoreApps\URShopi\src\URShopi\.\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0
System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: ''server'.
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Dictionary`2 parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Dictionary`2 synonyms)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Dictionary`2 synonyms)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey key)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseModelFactory.Create(String connectionString, TableSelectionSet tableSelectionSet)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory.Create(String connectionString, TableSelectionSet tableSelectionSet)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.SqlServerScaffoldingModelFactory.Create(String connectionString, TableSelectionSet tableSelectionSet)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.ReverseEngineeringGenerator.GetMetadataModel(ReverseEngineeringConfiguration configuration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.ReverseEngineeringGenerator.GenerateAsync(ReverseEngineeringConfiguration configuration, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DatabaseOperations.ScaffoldContextAsync(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemas, IEnumerable`1 tables, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.<ScaffoldContextImpl>d__22.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.EnumerableHelpers.ToArray[T](IEnumerable`1 source, Int32& length)
   at System.Collections.Generic.EnumerableHelpers.ToArray[T](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass4_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Keyword not supported: ''server'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quotes from your connection string

Answer (score 0):

**First add the following nuget packages:**

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools –Pre

Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design
```

**After that open your project.json file and make the following changes**

**Under dependencies add:**

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
```

"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",

**and under tools add:**

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
```

After making the changes Save the file.

**And finally Run the Command again - in the Package Manager Console:**

Scaffold-DbContext "Server=.;Database=dbname;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models